# Shifting focus from one component to another

Tags: java, swing, focus, jcomponent, setfocus

How can I shift focus from one component to another component when I *(program)* experience's' a certain case ? Like the focus shifts to the next text-field when in the first text field the word length reaches 3.

Comment: not clear your question, do you want to switch focus from one JComponent to another, if first reached three Chars, these three Chars including WhiteSpace Chars <e.g. Space ...>

Comment: @ mKorbel Actually not the white-space but i wanted to know a method that could shift focus from one component to another.

Comment: is possible by implements DocumentListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Subscribe to `keyDown` event on 1st component.
2. if `text length == 3` shift focus to another component. don't forget to undo the effect of current key down
3. I guess `focus()` OR `requestFocusInWindow()` method can be used. don't remember exact name.

Similarly, `TextChanged` event can be subscribed. so, ASA 3 chars are added, shift the focus using step 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
if(jTextField1.getText().length() == 2 ){ // if the req. length is 3
        // shift the focus to next text field
        jTextField2.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well..

```
 Component currentFocusOwner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
                            FocusEvent focusLostEvent = new FocusEvent(currentFocusOwner, 1005, true, destinationComponent);
                            FocusEvent focusGainEvent = new FocusEvent(destinationComponent, 1004, true, currentFocusOwner);                        
                            try
                            {
                                currentFocusOwner.dispatchEvent(focusLostEvent);
                                destinationComponent.dispatchEvent(focusGainEvent);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                Logger.logExceptionMessage(e);
                            }
```